# Why does MVC website on host logs off permanently after login?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, web-config, localhost, host

I uploaded my MVC website on hosting. But when I logon to the site, it permanently logs off.
This doesn't occur locally.
I have no clue about the cause of this problem.

**Web.config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login"  timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="SmsMenu.Services.CustomRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

**Edit:**

**This the code to login:**

**LoginController:**

```
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {
    private SmsDBEntities db = new SmsDBEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("admin") )
      {
        return RedirectToAction("Insurance", "Insurance", new { area = "AdminsArea" });
      }          
      return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel userModel)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        CustomRoleProvider customRole = new CustomRoleProvider();
        var id = customRole.ValidateUser(userModel);
        if (id != null)
        {
          Session["UserId"] = id;
          Session["Username"] = userModel.UserName;
          string[] roles = customRole.GetRolesForUser(userModel.UserName.ToString());

          customRole.CreateCookie(userModel);

          foreach (var item in roles)
          {
            if (item == "admin")
            {
              return RedirectToAction("Insurance", "Insurance", new { Area = "adminsarea" });
            }   
          }
        }
      }

      return View();
  }
```

**Functions:**

```
  public void CreateCookie(LoginViewModel member)
  {                                
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(member.UserName, member.RememberMe);
    //save login log in db          
  }
```

Comment: by seeing at web config part it is very hard to tell whats the problem. you can check authorization code whether it is proper or not?

Comment: @akhlesh i have added some code in my question.

Comment: open your web dev tools (F12 on chrome and firefox) and observe the network tab, might help.